# Java if statement not executing.

Tags: java, calendar, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
>   [java == vs equals() confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

So, I am trying to develop an application that opens a JDialog at a time I enter. It only needs t be accurate to a second.

```
public void run() {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    timeset = "16:37";

    while(true){

    System.out.println("thread sleep");
    try{Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);}catch(InterruptedException ie){}

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.getTime();
    temptime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());       
    System.out.println("realtime = " + realtime);
    System.out.println("timeset = " + timeset);

    if(realtime == timeset){

        System.out.println("if statement activated");
        Alert.man();
        break;

    }
```

So, my problem is when I run the programme the if statement doesn't run when timeset and realtime are equal and I just can't figure it out. What's the deal?

Comment: Note that the comparison of pointers vs values is a very basic concept (in most languages) that you need to "get", if you want to become a programmer.  It doesn't just apply to strings.

Comment: I'm beginning to "get" it now. I've only just begun writing code, so I'm learning new things all the time and this is just one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use equals() method to check if two dates are equal. `==` operator just checks if two references point to the same instance.

```
if(realtime == timeset){
```

should be

```
if(realtime.equals(timeset)){
```

Comment: The compare should take into account that you might not compare exactly on that second.  The sleep is for one second, and one could have enough variation from one cycle to the next to miss a second.

Comment: Thanks very much, that fixed it. Sorry about the vague question, I was finding it hard to articulate my thoughts into a title.

Comment: @HotLicks true that, i completely agree with your statement ..